# MVC Core adding Drop Down List to view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to populate a drop down list in a view.  I'm having problems with the razor syntax (I believe--only a couple days into this framework).  I have seen multiple ways to do this; however, I'm interested in getting this to work so I can learn from it...:).  Here's what I've got:
My DataAccess Class:

```
public class DropDown{
public List<SelectListItem> Get_State() //State

    {
        using (SqlConnection conSql = new SqlConnection(conStr)) 
        {
            if (conSql.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conSql.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * From Select_State Order by State", conSql);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds);

            List<SelectListItem> stateList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)

            {
                stateList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["StateName"].ToString(), Value = dr["State"].ToString() });
            }

            return stateList;
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
    public class DropDownModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> State { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> extra1{ get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> extra2{ get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> extra3{ get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> extra4{ get; set; }
}
```

}

My Controller:

```
        public IActionResult DropDown() {
                  DropDownModel dropdown = new DropDownModel();
                  dropdown.State = Get_DropDown.Get_State();

        return View(dropdown);
    }//DropDown
```

How do I get the razor syntax to display a drop down list with states in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the exact issue is because this is pretty straight-forward. In your view, you'd simply do:

```
<select asp-for="SomeProperty" asp-items="@Model.State"></select>
```

Where `SomeProperty` would be the property on your model you want to bind the selected value to on post. Alternatively, you can use the `HtmlHelper` extension:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty, Model.State)
```

Comment: The issue is I don't know what I'm doing - still trying to learn it :).  However, your answer did it.  Not sure what was going on.  I had something close to that at one time and it didn't work, but when I used your answer it worked fine...must have had a spelling/case error that I wasn't seeing.  Thanks!!!